# ASP.NET MVC calling server from javascript function with ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call the following action method in a controller from a javascript function in a partial view:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RemoveNotifications(IList<Notification> notifications)
    {
        Context.Notifications.RemoveRange(notifications);
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

This is the function that should call the server from the view:

```
function show(message) {
    message += "</ul>"
    document.getElementById('notifications').innerHTML = message;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("RemoveNotifications", "Notification")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'notifications': "@Model.Notifications" },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

The first part works fine, but the $.ajax part dosen't do anything. I also have the following added at the top of my view:

```
<script src="TandForum.dk/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="TandForum.dk/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="TandForum.dk/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `@Model.Notifications` will return a string (something like `"System.Collections.Generic.IList<Notification>"`, not the collection. What is the point of this. You sent the collection to the view from the controller so you already know what it is. There is no reason to send it from the view to the controller, just get the same collection again in the `RemoveNotifications()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `@Model.Notifications` into the `data` parameter it is attempting to serialize it so that it can be passed to the controller action. Because javascript has no knowledge of how your `Notification` class is constructed, this will not work.

If you need to specify which Notifications are to be removed, it would be better to pass to the action a collection of Notification IDs, so for example if your `Notification` class has a property of type `int` called `Id` then your method becomes:

```
public JsonResult RemoveNotifications(IEnumerable<int> notificationIds)
{
    Context.Notifications.RemoveAll(n => notificationIds.Contains(n.Id));
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

But if you always want to remove all Notifications, just use the same collection that you used to populate the view in the first place, as the comment above mentions.